# Is there a way to override the Azure Repos name length limit of 64 characters?

Tags: git, azure, azure-devops, azure-repos

According to the documentation (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/settings/naming-restrictions?view=azure-devops) the limit is set to 64 characters.

Is there a way to override this somehow? For reference Github has a limit of 100 characters. If it matters we are using Azure DevOps Server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can reproduce the same issue in Azure DevOps Service and Azure DevOps Server.

[image]

I am afraid that there is no method can override the limitation of Azure Repo Name length.

The 64 characters limitation related to Azure Repo Name exists for both the Azure DevOps Service and Azure DevOps Server.

I can fully understand your requirement. You can submit a suggest ticket in the site: [Developer Community](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/AzureDevOps/suggest) to report this feature.

Comment: Thanks for confirming. I will submit a suggestion like you wrote.